# Precalculus/Trigonometric Functions of Sine, Cosine, and Tangent with given parameters?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

for my precalculus class I was given an assignment for extra credit however it is some material that I have yet to cover or learn as far as sine, cosine, and tangent go. Below is the prompt that I was given:

If `sin α = 3/13` where `0 < α < π/2` and `cos β = -2/9` where `π < β < 3π/2`, determine the following:

1. sin(α - β)
2. cos(β - α)
3. tan(2β)
4. cos(4β)
5. cot(α + β)

I am not quite sure of the first step to take on these. I wasn't able to find much online either due to my search terms or what not. I hate to upload such a blank question however I am at a loss for how to approach these questions...

Comment: Possible start : [trig identities](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html). Also, use `$\alpha, \beta$` for Greek letters $\alpha, \beta$, Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You need several standard relations: $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A,\cos(A+B)=\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B$ and $\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$. For (4) you need a similar more complicated expression. You can work them out fairly easily if you are familiar with $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

Comment: Use the double angle formulas, for example the first one $$sin(\alpha - \beta) = sin(\alpha)cos(\beta) - sin(\beta)cos(\alpha)$$ and then substitute in your values, i.e. you know $sin(\alpha) = \frac{3}{13}$ and $cos(\beta) = \frac{-2}{9}$

Comment: OP, the **first step** that you should take is to solve the two [right] triangles that are represented in the prompt. Every single one of these comments and answers seems to assume that *you know how to do this*, but I'm guessing you do NOT.

Answer (score 3):

They require you to use the identities: $$\sin(\alpha\pm \beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta \pm \cos \alpha \sin \beta$$ $$\cos (\alpha\pm \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta \mp \sin \alpha \sin \beta$$
From these one can infer the double-angle formulae:
$$\sin 2\alpha = 2\sin \alpha\cos \alpha$$ $$\cos 2\alpha = \cos^2 \alpha -\sin^2 \alpha = 2\cos^2 \alpha -1 =1-2\sin^2 \alpha$$ $$\tan 2\alpha = \frac {2\tan \alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}$$
To find the value of $\sin\beta$ or $\cos\alpha$, draw a triangle with the lengths of two sides given by the fractions $\frac 3 {13}$ or $\frac {-2} 9$. Use Pythagoras' Theorem to find the length of the third side, and infer the value of $\sin\beta$ or $\cos\alpha$.

[image: Triangles]

You could use the CAST diagram to work out whether $\sin\beta$ and $\cos\alpha$ are positive or negative, by looking at where the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lie in a circle.

Comment: Upvote for the edit. OP probably doesn't know how to solve a right triangle!

Answer (score 0):

Applying the expressions

$$\sin(\alpha-\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta$$

$$\cos(\beta-\alpha)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta$$

$$\tan(2\beta)=\frac{2\sin\beta\cos\beta}{\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\beta}$$

$$\cos(4\beta)=\cos^2(2\beta)-\sin^2(2\beta)=(\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\beta)^2-(2\sin\beta\cos\beta)^2$$

$$\cot(\alpha+\beta)=\frac{\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha\cos\beta-\cos\alpha\sin\beta}$$

where you can get

$$\cos\alpha=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}$$

$$\sin\beta=-\sqrt{1-\cos^2\beta}$$

because cosine is positive in the first quadrant and sine negative in the third.

Answer (score -1):

If you want calculate this, you can use this site: http://www.milefoot.com/math/trig/22anglesumidentities.htm.

With those formulas your work is just analyze the signals of the functions in these intervals, can you do it or you don't know how analyze the signals ?

Comment: While this link may be useful in answering the question, the essential parts of your answer should be provided here.